# Changing the way Firefox opens images. Is this possible?

Tags: firefox, images

When opening a big image file directly in Firefox, I have seen 3 kinds of opening. Image opens:

1. From top to bottom
2. From bottom to top
3. From blurry to clear (in full dimensions)

I have mostly seen the first one happening (You may try this [example](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Los_Angeles,_CA_from_the_air.jpg)). Is there a setting to change the way an image opens in Firefox, or is it just random? I'd prefer the third one as default.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 11, if it matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How the image displays depends on what type of image it is. [Progressive-encoded images](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html) go from blurry to clear. BMPs go from bottom to top. The rest go from top to bottom.

Comment: No way to hack it from settings or using an addon?

Comment: I'm sure you could, but it would have to wait until the entire image is downloaded, at which point you could just, you know, display it.

Answer (score 0):

1. using javascript you can wait for images to load, then set their display property to 'not none'
2. using greasemonkey add-on  you can run javascripts on any page - only problem: maybe it does so after the page/images already been loaded
3. however, it is possible to run some scripts before even that, i.e ABP does that - it sets images (blocked ones) to display:none.

so on conclusion, it is possible, using add-on with that simple script code.